# Compact way to generate checkerboard pattern

Tags: java, optimization, design-patterns, performance

I need to generate a checkerboard pattern for a game that I am creating. I have come up with the following (pseudo)code, but feel there must be a more compact way to do this. All suggestions welcome!

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++){
        if (i % 2 == 1){
            if (j % 2 ==1){
                color = white
            }
            if (j % 2 ==0){
                color = black
            }
        }

        if (i % 2 == 0){
            if (j % 2 ==1){ 
                color = black
            }
            if (j % 2 ==0){
                color = white
            }
        }
        id = (i-1)*8+j
    }//end inner for
}//end outer for
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++){
        if ( i+j % 2 == 0 ) {
            color = white;
        } else {
            color = black;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I suspected a test for evenness would help! Thanks.

Comment: Gets me an alternating grid color for any x/y coord in a grid. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you swap colours after each time you draw something, that should accomplish this.
eg.

```
Start with black
Outer loop i
   Inner loop j
      Print colour square at position i,j
      Swap colours
```

Should then go, for an odd numbered board
eg. 
3x3

```
bwb
wbw
bwb
```

Comment: Would this still work for an even numbered board? If I swap the color in the inner loop, then for a 4x4 board I would get:  
wbwb  
wbwb  
wbwb  
wbwb  
.  
It seems that using this methodology I would have to add a check to not swap the color if the inner loop has reached the end.

Comment: You're right... it won't work for even numbered boards. Teepeemm has the superior solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum with a successor method. Then you can initialise as follows:

- The colour of position(col = 0, row = 0) is Colour.Black or Colour.White depending on where you define your origin to be.
- The colour of position(col = 0, row = n) is the successor of position(col = 0, row = n-1).
- In each row the colour of position(col = m, row = n) is the successor of position(col = m-1, row = n).

Here is the Colour enum:

```
public enum Colour {
    BLACK, WHITE;
    public Colour successor() {
        // Bulky general implementation.
        //return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];

        // Simpler version for our binary case.
        return equals( BLACK ) ? WHITE : BLACK;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution where you can choose the number of pixels for a square side, and the total number of squares on the checkerboard's sides.

```
int dimSq = 10;         // in pixels
int dimBoard = 8;       // in squares
int pixels = dimSq * dimBoard;
for (int x = 0; x < pixels; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < pixels; y++)
        boolean black = (x / dimSq) + (y / dimSq) % 2 == 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++){
        if (i % 2 == j % 2){
            color = white
        } else {
            color = black
        }
        id = (i-1)*8+j
    }//end inner for
}//end outer for
```

Go through all of the tiles, and if they're both even or both odd (i.e. (1,1), (1,3)... and (2,2) (2,4) (2,6)... and (3,1) (3,3) (3,5) ... etc) then make it one color, otherwise use the other color

Example:

```
B W B W B W
W B W B W B
B W B W B W
W B W B W B
B W B W B W
W B W B W B
```

You check out the indices where the colors are all black here and you will see that at all of these, the X and Y are either both odd or both even.

Also, not sure what exactly your `id = (i-1)*8+j` line is supposed to be doing

Comment: This will have 3 B for each W.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yeah, fixed it, I changed my test code in eclipse and reflected that in my explanation but I never fixed it in the code here before posting :P Should be good now

Comment: The ID is numbering the tiles 1-64.

Comment: @vaniaspeedy Actually I think it is supposed to be 1-8 for x,y (which combined is effectively 1-64)

Answer (score -1):

one-liner

```
int dim = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < dim * dim; i++) System.out.print((i % dim == 0 ? "\n" : "") + ((i / dim) % 2 == 0 ? i % 2 == 0 ? 'B' : 'W' : i % 2 == 0 ? 'W' : 'B') + " ");
```

output

```
B W B W B W B W B W 
W B W B W B W B W B 
B W B W B W B W B W 
W B W B W B W B W B 
B W B W B W B W B W 
W B W B W B W B W B 
B W B W B W B W B W 
W B W B W B W B W B 
B W B W B W B W B W 
W B W B W B W B W B
```

Comment: That's two lines.  Three if you put the print on the next line after the for statement.  :P

Comment: Not wrapping your lines doesn't optimize it; it's still got some inefficiencies

Comment: The original question is about finding a more compact way to do this, not more optimal way. String{Buffer|Builder} are much better for this.